# jquery - ajax synchronous api calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, asynchronous

Can I make use of jQuery AJAX API and make a synchronous calls other than using

```
async = false
```

because I need to use the data from get request which is in a different file to call a jquery function along with the data that I receive from ajax call and then continue with the rest of the code execution.

I tried using **$.when** but with not much success.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I explained it propoerly so, all I want is to stop the page execution, get ajax api call data and proceed with page execution once the data is available. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will either need to put async: false , efectively making it a synchronous call instead of an ajax one, or if i understood your question correctly, you need 2 calls to finish then use their data together to call a function.
You will have to manually synchronise the results on the callback, your logic should be

```
var data1 = "";
var data2 = "";
jQuery.ajax().done(function(data){
 data1 = data;
 if( data1 != "" && data2 != "") {
   doFunction(data1,data2);
 }
});
jQuery.ajax().done(function(data){
 data2 = data;
 if( data1 != "" && data2 != "") {
   doFunction(data1,data2);
 }
});
```

or do ajax inside an ajax

```
jQuery.ajax().done(function(data){
 var data1 = data;
 jQuery.ajax().done(function(data2){
     doFunction(data1,data2);
 });
});
```